# iTunes MiniPlayer replacement

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation

I finally was forced to upgrade to iTunes 11 in order to upgrade my iPhone's operating system. I think I can get a reasonable replacement to iTunes DJ with smart playlists, but the one thing that is killing me is the new MiniPlayer.

The two issues I have with it are that it doesn't show the time remaining in my track, and that it doesn't scroll long track names (except once at the beginning of the track).

Now, if it is indeed possible to do this, I'd love to hear how, but I am not very hopeful.

Are there any good MiniPlayer replacements out there? The only ones I found were for Windows.  I'd just like some kind of small persistant window that shows me what is playing in iTunes.

Comment: Honestly, what I really like is the iTunes main window title bar. If there were some way to just show that, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[Cover Sutra](http://sophiestication.com/coversutra/) has a nice player bezel, which, while larger than the iTunes MiniPlayer, has more info (such as a progress bar). If it was smaller, and offered the ability to change the color (it's black), I'd want to keep it visible all the time.

Answer (score 1):

**You Control: Tunes** can be found here: http://www.yousoftware.com/tunes/

You can also check **Skip Tunes** here: http://skiptunes.com

Comment: Hmm. Their site must have been down when I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that one of the programs I've already been using has a partial solution to this.  I don't think it will completely suit my needs, but I'll post it here for completeness.  You Control iTunes let's you create a ticker in the menubar that lists the current track name and artist.  This solves one of the problems.

Unfortunately, the site for it seems to be gone.  If anyone knows where it can be downloaded, please edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, [Bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com/).  It has a lot of "themes", which basically means a bunch of different kinds of miniplayers.  Unfortunately, half of the themes don't work, and it doesn't seem to be possible to move the miniplayer to another monitor, which is a deal breaker for me.

Comment: Have you tried putting iTunes into full screen mode? Does the MiniPlayer appear on a second monitor if you do? I found that full screen mode is the only way to get the MiniPlayer to display in all spaces (I use spaces, with iTunes in its own space.)

Comment: I'm talking about the Bowtie miniplayer, not iTunes's.  The iTunes miniplayer works just fine in separate monitors.

Comment: Ok, sorry. But the iTunes MiniPlayer isn't happy with spaces, oddly.